# Suppose you are asked to design the first ascent and drop for a new roller coaster

Tags: calculus, derivatives

By studying the photographs of your favorite coasters, you decide to make the slope of the ascent 0.7 and the slope of the drops -1.5. You decide to connect these two straight stretched $y = L_1(x)$ and $y = L_2(x)$ with part of a parabola $f(x) = ax^2+bx+c$, where $x$ is measured in feet. For the track to be smooth there can't be abrupt changes in direction, so you want the linear segments $L_1$ and $L_2$ to be tangent to the parabola at the points $P$ and $Q$. To simplify the equations, you decide to place the origin at $P (P= (0,0).$ Additionally, suppose the horizontal distance between $P$ and $Q$ is 100ft.

1.) Write the equations using the variables a,b and c so that the conditions given above are satisfied. Use the equations to determine $f(x) = ax^2+bx+c. $

2.) Determine the coordinates for $Q$.

3.) Plot $L_1, f$, and $L_2$ together to verify graphically that the roller coaster you are designing is smooth at the points $P$ and $Q$.

I tried finding the derivative of $ax^2+bx+c$ and used that, $2ax+b$, to find the value of $b$ which is 0.7. I also found the equation of line one which is $y=0.7x$ at $p (0,0)$ and it is tangent. I also determined that $a = -0.011$ from the derivative. So Im missing the $c$ value for $-.011x^2+0.7x+c=y$ and the coordinates for point $Q$ along with its equation $L_2$.

Comment: This kind of looks like you just typed your homework problem in the box.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I tried finding the derivative of ax^2+bx+c and used that, 2ax+b to find the value of b which is 0.7. I also found the equation of line one which is y=0.7x at p (0,0). I also determined that a = -0.011 from the derivative.

Comment: Good.  Please edit your original post to include what you have figured out so far (including your work) and what your actual question is.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I made the changes.

Comment: Actually, for the coaster to be ridable, one would require not only tangency (continuous first derivative), but in fact a continuos second derivative. Else you will end up with a "wild mouse", a coaster that is wilder than it looks.

Comment: You're mostly done! Remember that the parabola and first line meet at the origin $P$.  Also, the horizontal distance between $P$ and $Q$ is 100, so what does that tell you about the $x$-coordinate of $Q$?  The parabola and second line meet at $Q$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen If you add that assumption the problem isn't solvable.  Good feedback for the problem author, though! :-)

Comment: @MatthewLeingang well I know that coordinate $Q$ is at $(100,y)$ but I can't solve that without my $c$ value.

Comment: "Remember that the parabola and the first line meet at the origin $P$" <-- does that help with $c$?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Well if I plug 0 in my quadratic and set $y$ to 0 as well then I get $c=0$ which can't be right.

Comment: Why is $c=0$ not right?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang then the distance between p and q would only be 63

Comment: But the constraint is on the horizontal distance between the two points.

Comment: Oh you're right it can be 0 so Q is (100,-40)

Comment: @MatthewLeingang okay I got it now . Thanks for the tips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) $f(x) = -0.011x^2+0.7x$

2.) $Q:(100,-40)$

3.) $L_1 = y = .7x$ $L_2 = (y+40)=-1.5(x-100)$

Comment: Please show your working if you want this to be considered as a complete answer. Alternatively, include this as supplementary information in the question itself.